# How to plot negative x and y values on canvas

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

Starting point of a canvas is top left corner that is x,y(0,0). I can plot positive values on canvas.

[image]

Below is my sample code

```
<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(200,100);
ctx.stroke();
</script>
```

but i can't plot x and y if value of x and y is negative. Code below is not working

```
<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(-200,-100);
ctx.stroke();
</script>
```

I want to plot negative values on canvas. Is this possible?

**this is what i want**

[image]

Comment: This might help you, Please see this https://codepen.io/jkantner/pen/zMrKLJ

Comment: Add `ctx.translate(200,100)` before the move to command. You need to move the context in order to see the line.

Comment: Why didn't you accept the current answer ? I had your problem and that answer solved it

Answer (score 1):

You can position the origin (0,0) where ever you like with either, `ctx.translate`, `ctx.transform`, or `ctx.setTransform`.

`ctx.translate`, `ctx.transform` are relative to the current transform. `ctx.setTransform` is absolute.

The easiest way I find is to use `ctx.setTransform`

```
   const W = ctx.canvas.width, H = ctx.canvas.height;
   ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // resets the transform to clear
   ctx.clearRect(0,0,W,H); // clears the canvas

   ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, W / 2, H / 2); // moves the origin to the center of
                                               // the canvas

   ctx.strokeRect(-200,-200, 190, 190);
```

The 6 arguments for `setTransform` are.

- first 2 the vector describing the top edge of a rendered pixel. The X axis `x : 1, y : 0`
- second 2 the vector describing the left edge of a rendered pixel. The Y axis `x : 0, y : 1`
- last 2 the location in canvas pixels, of the top left of rendered pixel 0,0

Thus you can scale  by changing the first four

```
ctx.setTransform(2, 0, 0, 2, W / 2, H / 2); // zooms in by 2 with origin at center
ctx.setTransform(0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, W / 2, H / 2); // zooms out by 2 with origin at center
```